# Referencing a namespace while an identical namespace is within the current namespace

Tags: c#

I have a DLL I reference that has a namespace of

```
Model
```

with a class being

```
Item
```

so Model.Item is something I am trying to reference.

However in my project I am at a namespace of

```
Logic.Section
```

and in this is also included

```
Logic.Model
```

with various classes below it.

So when I try to reference the DLL of Model.Item, it won't let me because it only jumps back to Logic.Model

I normally restructure my namespace in this case, but is there a way to tell it to start at the highest level namespaces and go back down.

Comment: I'd say make your namespaces more specific/explicit.

Comment: Please consider restructuring your namespaces. It just improves readability and maintainability.

Comment: Eric blogged about namespace collisions here. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a namespace alias

```
using Co = Company.Proj.Nested;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx

or in your case something like

```
using M = Model
```

Comment: I don't like that because it just hides poor namespace design.

Comment: @meilke: Sometimes you have no control over that.  If you are not on a solo/small team project or the lead architect, you sometimes have to make the best of a bad situation.

Comment: or you could use using outside of your namespace

Answer (score 1):

`is there a way to tell it to start at the highest level namespaces and go back down.`

```
using global::Model.Item;
```

Answer (score 0):

this can happen in any 3rd Party DLLs, libraries , normally what i do is to name the namespace like

```
using myModelInMyDll = Model.Item
```

and then use myModelInMyDll

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [global namespace alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx), to force the namespace resolution to start at the highest level. So, within the `Logic` namespace

```
using Model; // resolves to Logic.Model
using global::Model; // resolves to Model.
```

If you have many class and namespace names clashing, you should consider reworking your naming strategy. If this is the result of a third-party library, as it sometimes is, you can [alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) the used classes:

```
using MyModel = global::Model; //aliases the namespace, so use MyModel.Item
using MyItem = global::Model.Item; //aliases the class, so use MyItem
```